# How can I optimize a query involving a subselect in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
id | price | group1
1  | 6     | some_group
2  | 7     | some_group
3  | 8     | some_group
4  | 9     | some_other_group
```

If I want to select the lowest price grouped by `group1`

I can just do this:

```
SELECT id, min(price), group1 FROM some_table GROUP BY group1;
```

The problem is when I have a table which is not sorted by price like this:

```
id | price | group1
1  | 8     | some_group
2  | 7     | some_group
3  | 6     | some_group
4  | 9     | some_other_group
```

Then my query returns this result set:

```
id | price | group1
1  | 6     | some_group
4  | 9     | some_other_group
```

The problem is that I get `1` in the `id` column but the `id` of the row with the price of `6` is not `1` but `3`. 
My question is that how can I get the values from the row which contains the minimum price when I use `GROUP BY`?

I tried this:

```
SELECT f.id, min(f.price), f.group1 FROM (SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY price) f
GROUP BY f.group1;
```

but this is really slow and if I have multiple columns and aggregations it may fail.

Please note that the names above are just for demonstration purposes. My real query looks like this:

```
SELECT depdate, retdate, min(totalprice_eur) price FROM
    (SELECT * FROM flight_results
     WHERE (
     fromcity = 30001350
     AND tocity = 30001249
     AND website = 80102118
     AND roundtrip = 1
     AND serviceclass = 1 
     AND depdate > date(now()))
     ORDER BY totalprice_eur) F
WHERE (
fromcity = 30001350
AND tocity = 30001249
AND website = 80102118
AND roundtrip = 1
AND serviceclass = 1
AND depdate > date(now()))
GROUP BY depdate,retdate
```

and there is a concatenated primary key including `website`, `fromcity`, `tocity`, `roundtrip`, `depdate`, and `retdate`. There are no other indexes.

Explain says:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2837    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED flight_results  ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    998378  Using filesort
```

Comment: What indexes do you have, and what data types are the fields. The solution below should be efficient which suggests the performance is down to the table design. Can you run an EXPLAIN of the below query and paste the results?

Comment: As an aside, your current SQL that appears to work but is too slow is not certain to keep working. MySQL does often bring the first value for any non aggregate / non group by fields in the select but this is not guaranteed. Which one is returned is not defined and may change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this instead:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.price, t1.group1
FROM some_table AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT min(price) minprice, group1 
  FROM some_table 
  GROUP BY group1
) AS t2 ON t1.price = t2.minprice AND t1.group1 = t2.group1;
```

Comment: If you can see my draft answer it looks copy-paste :D. beat me by 2 secs. +1.